Integrating and Synchronysing Active Directory on Windows Server and OpenLDAP on Ubuntu
I'm actually working on a project, which is based on the centralized management of servers...
I've installed and configured Active Directory on Windows server 2022 and equally installed and configured OpenLDAP server and its web client LAM on Ubuntu 2022...
And now I'm looking for a way to integrate and synchronize both directory services together, so that users can be able to authenticate to both with the same credentials and access the stored information in both directories...
Can someone help me with ideas on how this can be done please ???
I tried using Microsoft Identity Manager, but this seems to be complicated...
I'm looking for a suitable way to do this task.
